# XSL: xsl:when not working during the recursion

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a template which detects an apostrophe or a quote (") and adds before a "\" in a text.
It works when the text contains just apostrophes or just quotes. But when it contains both, 
the second    `xsl:when`    is not working.

```
 `<xsl:template name="replace-string">
    <xsl:param name="text" />
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test='contains($text,"&apos;") '>
            <xsl:value-of select='substring-before($text,"&apos;")' />
            <xsl:text>&#92;&apos;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:call-template name="replace-string">
                <xsl:with-param name="text"
                    select='substring-after($text,"&apos;")' />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="contains($text,'&#34;')">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,'&#34;')" />
            <xsl:text>&#92;&#34;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:call-template name="replace-string">
                <xsl:with-param name="text"
                    select="substring-after($text,'&#34;')" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$text" />
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>`
```

Example: 
`Some'text = Some\'text;
Some"text = Some\"text;
Some"text"another text = Some\"text\"another text;
Some'text"another'text = Some\'text"another\'text.`

Comment: The reason for this behavior is <xsl:choose> works like "switch" in Java, C, etc. It takes the first <xsl:when>, if true executes it and exits the <xsl:choose>, if not true, goes for the next <xsl:when> or <xsl:otherwise>. When you have both Apostrophe and Quotes, the string is processed based on the "Apostrophe" since your first <xsl:when> checks for Apostrophe's presence, thus not letting way for next <xsl:when> or <xsl:otherwise>. Try for this string and it will work: Some'text"anothertext

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following input XML when ran against the below XSLT will solve your problem:

```
<root>'Sometext'"anothertext'"</root>
```

XSLT code:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="text"/>
<xsl:variable name="Apos">'</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="Quot">"</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:call-template name="replace-string">
        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="*"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="replace-string">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:variable name="strBeforeApos" select='substring-before($text, $Apos)'/>
    <xsl:variable name="strBeforeQuot" select="substring-before($text, $Quot)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="char">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($text, $Apos) and contains($text, $Quot)">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="string-length($strBeforeApos) &lt; string-length($strBeforeQuot)">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$Apos"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$Quot"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="contains($text, $Apos)">
                <xsl:value-of select="$Apos"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="contains($text, $Quot)">
                <xsl:value-of select="$Quot"/>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="normalize-space($char) != ''">
            <xsl:value-of select='substring-before($text,$char)' />
            <xsl:text>&#92;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="$char"/>
            <xsl:call-template name="replace-string">
                <xsl:with-param name="text"
                select='substring-after($text, $char)' />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$text" />
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple method is to parametrize the template and call it twice, for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="escape-apos">
        <xsl:call-template name="escape-char">
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="input"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="char">'</xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>

    <output>
        <xsl:call-template name="escape-char">
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$escape-apos"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="char">"</xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="escape-char">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="char"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($text, $char)">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text, $char)"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('\', $char)"/>
            <xsl:call-template name="escape-char">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $char)"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="char" select="$char"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$text" />
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```